# I want to issue navigation and dispatch Redux action simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have form where user can choose one of two company types (two links). After selecting one link there must be transition to another page and redux state must be filled with chosen type. How can I achieve this in single transaction?

Comment: Have you considered using `<Route onEnter={dispatchAction}>`?

Comment: @Aaron No. Is there no redundant render in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it also depends on your action... is the action async? If it's not then I don't think there

Comment: <comment above got cut off> If your action is not async then I don't think you can dispatch it from anywhere without causing another render pass, but that's not usually a problem because of React's rendering system. Aggressive rendering is normal. If you *really* want to only have a single action, I think you'll need to handle the `react-router-redux` action `LOCATION_CHANGE` in your reducer. But even then it might cause 2 renders. I wouldn't worry about 2 renders. :)

Comment: @Aaron I'll agree with you about 2 renders. But I think implementing this scenario will break time traveling features. And using react-router-redux will become meaningless/